# Nginx Init.d script

Tags: nginx, vps

Hey i need some help with the Init.d script for Nginx
This is my Nginx files locations -

```
  nginx path prefix: "/usr/local/nginx"  nginx binary file: "/usr/local/nginx/nginx"
  nginx configuration prefix: "/usr/local/nginx"
  nginx configuration file: "/usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf"
  nginx pid file: "/usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid"
  nginx error log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log"
  nginx http access log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log"
```

And this is my Init.d script -

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          nginx
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the nginx web server
# Description:       starts nginx using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/nginx/nginx
NAME=nginx
DESC=nginx

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

# Include nginx defaults if available
if [ -f /usr/local/nginx/nginx ] ; then
        . /usr/local/nginx/nginx
fi

set -e

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid \
                --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid \
                --exec $DAEMON
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \
                /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid --exec $DAEMON
        sleep 1
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \
                /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  reload)
      echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration: "
      start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --pidfile /usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid \
          --exec $DAEMON
      echo "$NAME."
      ;;
  *)
        N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I try to modified it for my files location but its still doesn't work , what i need to change for make it work ?

Comment: Can you give us any log info ? what happens when you launch it from command line ?

Comment: This is what happened when i am launching it -

Comment: ñÿn¼r/local/nginx/nginx: 1: cannot open
ñÿÀ
å: No such file
/usr/local/nginx/nginx: 2:u¼
ñÿdÄ
_: not found
/usr/local/nginx/nginx: 8: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: In my opinion you have a) syntax error in nginx file (try to test the config file with nginx -t b) paths mismatch - typically nginx should reside in something like /prefix/whatever/sbin/nginx not in /prefix/whatever/nginx

Comment: I change this 2 lines PATH= , DAEMON= to this -

Comment: PATH=/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/opt/sbin/nginx

And its not shout any error but its just doesn't do anything the Nginx doesn't start

Comment: `sh -x /etc/init.d/nginx start` and post the output here.

Comment: + PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
+ DAEMON=/usr/local/sbin/nginx
+ NAME=nginx
+ DESC=nginx
+ test -x /usr/local/sbin/nginx
+ exit 0

Comment: Is it all you get?

Answer (score 3):

I've written this (initially took over from debian) for Gentoo and I suggest using it because it works and has better debug output:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"

BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
echo "Script location: ${BASEDIR}"

nginx="/usr/sbin/nginx"
prog=$(basename $nginx)

NGINX_CONF_FILE="${PWD}/../cfg/nginx.conf"

echo "Using config file: ${NGINX_CONF_FILE} "

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx

PS="nginx"
PIDNAME="nginx"             #lets you do $PS-slave
PIDFILE=$PIDNAME.pid                    #pid file
PIDSPATH=/var/run

DESCRIPTION="Nginx Server..."

RUNAS=root                              #user to run as

SCRIPT_OK=0                             #ala error codes
SCRIPT_ERROR=1                          #ala error codes
TRUE=1                                  #boolean
FALSE=0                                 #boolean

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                               Simple Tests
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#test if nginx is a file and executable
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

# Include nginx defaults if available
if [ -f /etc/default/nginx ] ; then
        . /etc/default/nginx
fi

#set exit condition
#set -e

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                               Functions
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

setFilePerms(){

        if [ -f $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE ]; then
                chmod 400 $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE
        fi
}

configtest() {
    $DAEMON -t -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
}

getPSCount() {
    return `pgrep -f $PS | wc -l`
}

isRunning() {
        if [ $1 ]; then
                pidof_daemon $1
                PID=$?

                if [ $PID -gt 0 ]; then
                        return 1
                else
                        return 0
                fi
        else
                pidof_daemon
                PID=$?

                if [ $PID -gt 0 ]; then
                        return 1
                else
                        return 0
                fi
        fi
}

#courtesy of php-fpm
wait_for_pid () {
        try=0

        while test $try -lt 35 ; do

                case "$1" in
                        'created')
                        if [ -f "$2" ] ; then
                                try=''
                                break
                        fi
                        ;;

                        'removed')
                        if [ ! -f "$2" ] ; then
                                try=''
                                break
                        fi
                        ;;
                esac

                #echo -n .
                try=`expr $try + 1`
                sleep 1
        done
}

status(){
    isRunning
    isAlive=$?

    if [ "${isAlive}" -eq $TRUE ]; then
                echo "$PIDNAME found running with processes:  `pidof $PS`"
        else
                echo "$PIDNAME is NOT running."
        fi


}

removePIDFile(){
    if [ $1 ]; then
                if [ -f $1 ]; then
                    rm -f $1
            fi
        else
        #Do default removal
        if [ -f $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE ]; then
                    rm -f $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE
            fi
        fi
}

start() {
        echo "Starting $DESCRIPTION"

    isRunning
    isAlive=$?

        if [ "${isAlive}" -eq $TRUE ]; then
                echo $SCRIPT_ERROR
        else
                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $RUNAS --pidfile $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON \
                -- -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
                setFilePerms
                echo $SCRIPT_OK
        fi
}

stop() {
    echo "Stopping $DESCRIPTION"

    isRunning
    isAlive=$?
        if [ "${isAlive}" -eq $TRUE ]; then
                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE

        wait_for_pid 'removed' $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE

                if [ -n "$try" ] ; then
                        echo $SCRIPT_ERROR
                else
                        removePIDFile
                    echo $SCRIPT_OK
                fi

        else
                echo $SCRIPT_ERROR
        fi
}

reload() {
    configtest || return $?

    echo "Reloading (via HUP) $DESCRIPTION"

        isRunning
        if [ $? -eq $TRUE ]; then
        `killall -HUP $PS` #to be safe

                echo $SCRIPT_OK
        else
                echo $SCRIPT_ERROR
        fi
}

quietupgrade() {
    echo "Peforming Quiet Upgrade $DESCRIPTION"

        isRunning
        isAlive=$?
        if [ "${isAlive}" -eq $TRUE ]; then
        kill -USR2 `cat $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE`
        kill -WINCH `cat $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE.oldbin`

        isRunning
        isAlive=$?
        if [ "${isAlive}" -eq $TRUE ]; then
            kill -QUIT `cat $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE.oldbin`
            wait_for_pid 'removed' $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE.oldbin
                        removePIDFile $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE.oldbin

            echo $SCRIPT_OK
        else
            echo $SCRIPT_ERROR

            echo "ERROR! Reverting back to original $DESCRIPTION"

            kill -HUP `cat $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE`
            kill -TERM `cat $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE.oldbin`
            kill -QUIT `cat $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE.oldbin`

            wait_for_pid 'removed' $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE.oldbin
                        removePIDFile $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE.oldbin

            echo $SCRIPT_ok
        fi
        else
                echo $SCRIPT_ERROR
        fi
}

terminate() {
        echo "Force terminating (via KILL) $DESCRIPTION"

    PIDS=`pidof $PS` || true

    [ -e $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE ] && PIDS2=`cat $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE`

    for i in $PIDS; do
        if [ "$i" = "$PIDS2" ]; then
                kill $i
                        wait_for_pid 'removed' $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE
            removePIDFile
        fi
    done

    echo $SCRIPT_OK
}

destroy() {
    echo "Force terminating and may include self (via KILLALL) $DESCRIPTION"
    killall $PS -q >> /dev/null 2>&1
    echo $SCRIPT_OK
}

pidof_daemon() {
    PIDS=`pidof $PS` || true

    [ -e $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE ] && PIDS2=`cat $PIDSPATH/$PIDFILE`

    for i in $PIDS; do
        if [ "$i" = "$PIDS2" ]; then
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
        ;;
  stop)
    stop
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
        ;;
  reload)
    $1
    ;;
  status)
    status
    ;;
  configtest)
        $1
        ;;
  quietupgrade)
    $1
    ;;
  terminate)
    $1
    ;;
  destroy)
    $1
    ;;
  *)
    FULLPATH=/etc/init.d/$PS
    echo "Usage: $FULLPATH {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status|configtest|quietupgrade|terminate|destroy}"
    echo "       The 'destroy' command should only be used as a last resort." 
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```